# Boost::thread how to synchronise between main and worker thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I am trying to achieve a multi-threaded design and need some help on thread synchronisation.

I have two classes, class A and class B. I'll explain using pseudo-code
class A is created in main function.

```
class A
{
   public:
   A();
   ~A();

   void tick();
   void addEntity();
   private:
   std::list<entity> entityList;
   B* _b;
};
```

Class B is as follows:

```
 class B
{
   public:
   B();
   ~B();

   void createSimulation();
   void startSimulation();
   void registerCallbacks(SimEngine& sim);
   void entityCreatedCallback();

   boost::signal<void()> signalEntityCreated;

   private:
   simEngine* sim;


};
```

Class A implementation is somewhat like that:

```
A::A()
{
    _b = new B();
    _b->signalEntityCreated.connect(boost::bind(&A::AddEntity, this));
    _b->createSimulation();
}

A::~A()
{

}

void A::tick()
{
    entity ent = entityList.pop_front();
    //process the entity
}


void A::addEntity(entity ent)
{
     entityList.push_back(entity);
}
```

Class B implementation is somewhat like that:

```
B::B()
{
}

B::~B()
{
}

 B::registerCallback(SimEngine& sim)
 {
     sim.connect("ENTITY_CREATED", entityCreatedCallback);
 }

 void B::createSimulation()
 {
     boost::thread sim_thread(boost::bind(&B::startSimulation, this));
 }


 void B::startSimulation()
 {
      sim =  new SimEngine();
      registerCallback(sim);

      sim->start();

 }

 void B::entityCreatedCallback(simEngine& sim)
{
    signalEntityCreated(sim.lastEntity);
}
```

So, main idea is class A creates class B, in turn class B start a simulation thread. before starting the simulation, it register some callback function with the simulation. these callbacks functions are called when some states changes in the simulation (i.e. entity created).

Class a uses boost signal slot mechanism to connect a signal (signalEntityCreated) in class B with a local member function in class A.
in Class B, callback call the signal to trigger the member function call in class A. In this case addEntity, which is adding new entry to the std::list.

Class A has a tick function that ticks in every frame, and need to process any entity that is added by the addEntity function.

Now, I need to properly synchronise this producing and consuming entity mechanism. class A is running in main thread and it is bind to render thread, so it cannot wait on mutex (for long) otherwise rendering performance can reduce.

My observation,
When simulation is running in different threads, all callbacks are belong to that thread. when member function in called using boost::signal that member function is also running in simulation thread. However, the processing (inside tick) needs to run in main thread.

any suggestion?

Comment: Where is `tick` called? In the future please make samples "real" and self-contained (names like `A` or `B` are only confusing and remove many helpful clues for experienced developers)

Answer (score 0):

You would just want to create a message queue that is polled from within the rendering event loop.

In addition, you could model the simulation and or renderer (`A`) follow the Active Object Pattern¹.

Note that when passing the event message across thread boundaries, you will want to pass the entity too, because otherwise there would be a race condition (when multiple entities have been created before the event is being handled).

---

¹ see e.g.
 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_object
 - http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/prefer-using-active-objects-instead-of-n/225700095 
 - 
 - https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Active_object#C.2B.2B is actually a nice example